# Custom RSA implementation in Javascript (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa

I've tried to implement the basics of RSA into a simple NodeJS / javascript file.

For encrypting I've used `c = m^e % n`.
For decrypting I've used `m = c^d % n`.

```
const p = 7; // choice prime
const q = 13; // choice prime
const n = p * q;
const e = 5; // choice
const Ke = [e, n]; // the private key
const d = 29; // choice
const Kd = [d, n]; // the public key

let message = 'hello'
let encrypted = []

message = message.toUpperCase()

for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
  const char = message.charCodeAt(i) - 64 // m
  const pow = Math.pow(char, e) // m^e
  const mod = pow % n // mod n
  encrypted[i] = mod
}

encrypted.forEach(char => {
  const pow = Math.pow(char, d) // c^d
  const mod = pow % n // mod n
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(mod + 64))
})
```

The encrypting goes well. However, the decrypting has some issues. It shows other characters then I've put in in the `let message = 'hello'` part

What am I doing wrong with decrypting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
encrypted.forEach(char => {
  const pow = Math.pow(char, d) // c^d
  const mod = pow % n // mod n
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(mod + 64))
})
```

In above function, pow is too large and precision is lost.
For example, in the case of 'L':

```
{ char: 38, d: 29, pow: 6.512148596632774e+45, mod: 81 }
```

Using a technique to calculate the mod of pow without losing precision, it can decode correctly.

```
encrypted.forEach(char => {
  let mod = 1
  for (let i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    mod = (mod * char) % n
  }
  console.log(String.fromCharCode(mod + 64))
})
```

output:

```
H
E
L
L
O
```